# PhpStorm - Create normal HTML, JS, CSS project

Tags: html, phpstorm

Is it possible to create a simple Project which only uses HTML, JavaScript and CSS, or do I have to use netbeans?

I tried to start a new project, but I have only these options:

[image]

and I am not sure what "HTML5 Boilerplate" is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the top most **"PHP Empty Project"** option.

If you do not have local or remote PHP -- just choose `<no interpreter>` option for "CLI Interpreter" field.

In the end you will get empty project.

---

Alternative solution:

1. Create empty project folder using your file manager/terminal.
2. Using PhpStorm use `Open` from Welcome screen (or `File | Open Directory` if you have some project already opened") and point to the project root folder -- IDE will create new project (or reuse existing one (if it finds `.idea` subfolder)) from those files.

---

> I am not sure what "HTML5 Boilerplate

You may click on blue link on the top right corner of that screen and it will take you to the GitHub page for that project.

From there: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate

> HTML5 Boilerplate is a professional front-end template for building fast, robust, and adaptable web apps or sites.
>
> This project is the product of many years of iterative development and combined community knowledge. It does not impose a specific development philosophy or framework, so you're free to architect your code in the way that you want.

Comment: I use Storm everyday for PHP/Laravel. So i have it configured with PHP interpreter. When creating a new empty project for HTML, Storm automatically grabs the PHP and offers it as an external library within the project. Annoying.

Comment: @Vince Please clarify your issue with some screenshots as I currently do not understand what problem you are facing. May worth posting as a separate question if it has much to describe.

Comment: Ok, as suggested I added a specific question with a screen shot. GUarantee someone will downvote it as already answered. Which I don't think it has been

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65483000/create-vanila-html-js-project-inside-phpstorm-where-php-has-already-been-confi