# Create Vanila HTML / JS project inside PhpStorm where PHP has already been configured

Tags: phpstorm

I use Storm daily for PHP/Laravel, and hence have PHP configured. When I want to create a vanilla HTML / JS side project, Storm takes it upon itself to add the PHP libraries without asking. I don't want any PHP Libraries. When initially creating the project, I used "empty project".

Here is a screen shot to illustrate.

[image: Project created for vanila HTML, JS, Vue]

So, how to create an empty project without PHP libraries?

Answer (score 2):

You are using PhpStorm, an IDE that supports PHP. That entry that you see there is a list of stubs for PHP (the stuff that IDE knows about core PHP and other common extensions: classes/functions/constants etc).

AFAIK it always will be there (as it's a PHP oriented IDE) and you cannot remove it. But you try this:

- `Settings (Preferences on macOS)`
- `Languages & Frameworks | PHP`
- `PHP Runtime` tab
- Uncheck ALL entries there.

If the above will not get rid of the whole node then you will have to ignore that entry. And I do not see any problems in having it here: it will not affect your JS/HTML in any way.

**P.S.** Whatever will be in a default/new project can be configured at `File | New Projects Settings | Settings for New Projects...`

Comment: Thanks ! I expected that much. To that end I considered down loading webstorm, but there is no community edit of such. No worries.